# Extract word between '=' and '('

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
234234=AWORDHERE('sdf.'aa')
```

where I need to extract `AWORDHERE`.

Sometimes there can be space in between.

```
234234= AWORDHERE('sdf.'aa')
```

Can I do this with a regular expression? 
Or should I do it manually by finding indexes?

The datasets are huge, so it's important to do it as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\d+=\s?(\w+)\(
```

<kbd>[Check Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ0yO0/3)</kbd>

in Javascript it would like that:

```
var myString = "234234=AWORDHERE('sdf.'aa')";// or 234234= AWORDHERE('sdf.'aa')
var myRegexp = /\d+=\s?(\w+)\(/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);  // AWORDHERE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this at least three ways.  You need to benchmark to see what's fastest.

1. Substring w/ indexes

   ```
   function extract(from) {
       var ixEq = from.indexOf("=");
       var ixParen = from.indexOf("(");

       return from.substring(ixEq + 1, ixParen);
   }
   ```

   .
2. Splits

   ```
   function extract(from) {
       var spEq = from.split("=");
       var spParen = spEq[1].split("(");

       return spParen[0];
   }
   ```
3. Regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA3uX2/1))

Here is some sample regex you could use

`/[^=]+=([^(]+).*/g`

This says

- `[^=]+` - One or more character which is not an `=`
- `=` - The `=` itself
- `(` - creates a matching group so you can access your match in code
- `[^(]+` - One or more character which is not a `(`
- `)` - closes the matching group
- `.*` - Matches the rest of the line

the `/g` on the end tells it to perform the match on all lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using `look around` you can search for string preceded by `=` and followed by `(` as following.

**Regex**: `(?<==)[A-Z ]+(?=\()`

**Explanation**:

`(?<==)` checks if `[A-Z ]` is preceded by an `=`.

`[A-Z ]+` matches your pattern.

`(?=\()` checks if matched pattern is followed by a `(`.

<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nF9bN9/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "234234= AWORDHERE('sdf.'aa')"; 
    var regexp = /.*=\s+(\w+)\(.*\)/g;
    var match = regexp.exec(str);
    alert( match[1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

I made my solution for this just a little more general than you asked for, but I don't think it takes much more time to execute. I didn't measure. If you need greater efficiency than this provides, comment and I or someone else can help you with that.

Here's what I did, using the command prompt of `node`:

```
> var s = "234234= AWORDHERE('sdf.'aa')"
undefined
> var a = s.match(/(\w+)=\s*(\w+)\s*\(.*/)
undefined
> a
[ '234234= AWORDHERE(\'sdf.\'aa\')',
  '234234',
  'AWORDHERE',
  index: 0,
  input: '234234= AWORDHERE(\'sdf.\'aa\')' ]
>
```

As you can see, this matches the number before the `=` in `a[1]`, and it matches the `AWORDHERE` name as you requested in `a[2]`. This will work with any number (including zero) spaces before and/or after the `=`.